# Go back through functions in my HTML

Tags: jquery

I have got a few functions in my HTML.

```
window.option1 = function () {
    $('div').empty().css('background-color','#1fc868').append('1');
}

window.option2 = function () {
    $('div').empty().css('background-color','#f8de41').append('2');
}

window.option3 = function () {
    $('div').empty().css('background-color','#f42731').append('3');
}
```

And a button to go back to a previous function

```
function goBack() { window.history.back(); }
```

But it brings me back to the previous page and not to functions I clicked before.

Please see the live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ay0zrhn6/

I am an absolute beginner and would be really grateful if you could amend my **jsfiddle** above to make it working.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible to do this with the standard browser "Go Back" feature. You can create an array to keep all your movements on this page and use it to go to previous state.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what's going on with your functions. You're just updating the DOM, not manipulating the browser history. Check out the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Your code is changing the DOM on the current page, not changing pages.  `window.history.back();` does just that, takes you back to the previous page.  You'll have to figure out how to track which option the user clicked previously, then take them back to that option with your code.

Comment: Hi @Roman could you please help me to do that if you have a spare minute please...

Comment: @qqruza it's not that simple, and a minute wouldn't be enough, at least for me, if you want to keep the whole history rather than just the last action...

Comment: @Roman I appreciate your honesty.

Answer (score 1):

Your "goBack" function does not "go back to a previous function"; as you've noted it goes back to the previous HTML page.

If you want your "goBack" function to invoke a previously invoked function you need to keep track of what the last function is yourself, so that your "goBack" function can use it.  For instance:

```
window.option1 = function () {
    $('div').empty().css('background-color','#1fc868').append('1');
    window.secondToLastFunction = window.lastFunction;
    window.lastFunction = 'option1';
}

window.option2 = function () {
    $('div').empty().css('background-color','#f8de41').append('2');
    window.secondToLastFunction = window.lastFunction;
    window.lastFunction = 'option2';
}

window.option3 = function () {
    $('div').empty().css('background-color','#f42731').append('3');
    window.secondToLastFunction = window.lastFunction;
    window.lastFunction = 'option3';
}

window.goBack = function() {
    var secondToLastFunction = window[window.secondToLastFunction];
    if (secondToLastFunction) {
        secondToLastFunction();
    } else {
        // do whatever you want to have happen when there is no
        // previous function to run
    }
}
```

As a side note, if you're going to be using functions to render (virtual) "pages" you might want to check out the Backbone framework. It has a "routers" which allow you to tie URLs (like '#foo') to functions so that you can better simulate "pages" using JavaScript.

And if you used a Backbone Router you actually could have the "back" button take you back to the previous (virtual) page.

Comment: Hi @machineghost I have added this code to my jsfiddle but it doesn't work properly please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4qtypze/1/

Comment: Ah, so it looks like you actually need a `secondToLastFunction` also; I'll edit my answer ... although as I said in my (previously edited) answer, you should really explore the Backbone framework, as it has all of the functionality I think you'd want built in.

Comment: I have added Backbone js to my jsfiddle but the back button still doesn't bring me to the previous function. http://jsfiddle.net/k4qtypze/4/
Can you please have a look and amend if possible?

Comment: I *highly* recommend learning how to use a browser developer tool, such as the Chrome debugging tool. If you just open up such a tool you'll see the problem with your fiddle, because there's an obvious error on the page. The problem is with `goBack`: you don't define it as `window.goBack = function() {...` so it doesn't work. As for Backbone, while I highly recommend learning/using it (and while I'm actually writing a book on that very topic), that's outside the scope of this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ay0zrhn6/2/). Easy and simple with jQuery.

```
$(function() {
  var colors  = ['#1fc868', '#f8de41', '#f42731', '#f452af', '#8d44b6'],
      counter = 0;

  $('button:not(:first-child)').click(function() {
    changeText($(this).text());
  });

  var changeText = function(text) {
    counter = parseInt(text);
    $('div').css('background-color', colors[counter - 1]).text(text);
  };

  $('button:first-child').click(function() {
    if (counter < 2) {
      return;
    }

    changeText(counter - 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @andr the changing colours is just an example. It should be a new json content loaded under each function. But thank you very much for your advice and consideration.

Comment: @qqruza Will buttons be changed? I mean their text (1, 2, 3...) ? If they won't, just replace colors array with JSON.